# How to set background-image (jquery) with Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, css, codeigniter

I'm working on a Codeigniter project. I have a `jQuery` file that sets `background-image` to the body:

```
$('body').css('background-image','url(<?php echo base_url("assets/images/bg2.png");?>)') ;
```

I tried this to set the image path, but doesn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: What is the output of your php code?

Answer (score 5):

You probably want this to make it like a normal CSS background-image declaration

`$('myOjbect').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');`

Comment: Yes that is what I want

Comment: that's great enjoy coding

Comment: @AdiKrasimirova if answer worked for you. You can accept answer